# New to Programming - Single Column Mean

Tags: r

In the exercises I've been assigned, it's asking for basic descriptive stats for each column of a data frame.  My table is called `SATGPA20R` and I tried `attach(SATGPA20R)` but did not get any results.  How can I calculate data for a single column?

Here is the data I'm working with:

```
ID  SEX State   SATV    SATM    GPA
2   1   1   1   590 590 3.20
3   2   1   1   670 660 3.03
4   3   1   1   540 520 2.69
5   4   1   2   620 600 3.06
6   5   1   3   610 510 3.03
7   6   1   1   560 500 3.03
8   7   1   3   480 590 3.48
9   8   1   2   620 560 3.62
10  9   1   1   510 610 3.21
11  10  1   1   630 530 3.73
12  11  1   2   580 530 3.51
13  12  1   2   490 560 3.04
14  13  2   2   620 540 3.02
15  14  2   3   520 550 3.01
16  15  2   3   620 620 3.47
17  16  2   2   480 530 2.90
18  17  2   1   500 630 2.87
19  18  2   1   640 560 2.38
20  19  2   1   390 430 2.41
21  20  2   1   540 520 2.56
```

Comment: Is `summary(SATGPA20R)` what you're looking for? For a single variable, you could use, for instance, `summary(SATGPA20R$GPA)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I gave that a try and got the following:
summary(SATGPA20R$GPA)
Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL 

I want to be able to summarize the entire column, with say sd, var, median, just simple descriptive info.

Comment: @EOwe21 - you clearly don't have a variable called `GPA` in your data.frame `SATGPA20R` - you get the result you describe for example with `dat <- data.frame(a=1); summary(dat$DOESNOTEXIST)` Check `colnames(SATGPA20R)` and make sure `GPA` is there - also remember R is case sensitive - `GPA` is not the same as `gpa`

Answer (score 3):

`attach` makes the fields in the data.frame available as ordinary variables, as in:

```
# make a simple data.frame
df <- data.frame(gpa = 1 + runif(50)*3)
# attach it to the search path
attach(df)

# use the field names as orinary variables
sd(gpa)
#> [1] 0.857903
mean(gpa)
#> [1] 2.686774
```

While it does save you a bit of typing to attach a data.frame, it obfuscates your code, making it difficult to figure out where a variable was defined.  This is usually not a great trade-off in practice so I would say away from it in favor of more descriptive code, like:

```
# access the fields via the $ and [ operators
sd(df$gpa)
#> [1] 0.857903
mean(df[,'gpa'])
#> [1] 2.686774
```

That said, if you want to calculate a summary statistic for each column of a data.frame, I like to use `lapply()` which takes advantage of the fact that data.frames are based on lists like so:

```
lapply(df, # the data.frame to be summarized
       sd) # the summary statistic.
```

If the summary statistic is an atomic value like a number, or constant length vector (as in the example from cryo111), it's convenient to use `sapply()` which will return a vector or matrix, where possible:

```
sapply(df, # the data.frame to be summarized
       sd) # the summary statistic. 

sapply(df,function(x) list(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x),var=var(x)))
```

Comment: Very thorough and nice summary!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in a `data.frame` you could use something like

```
lapply(df,function(x) list(mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x),var=var(x)))
```

You can include any statistics that you want.

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution. You can just use `sapply` and `summary` where the latter provides some statistical position measures (Mean, Median etc) and the first apply a function to every element of its argument, in this case if you have a data frame it applies the `summary` function to every column.

```
# generates a data frame
df <- data.frame( int = 1:10, random = rnorm(10) )
sapply(df, summary)

          int    random
Min.     1.00 -1.243000
1st Qu.  3.25 -0.642900
Median   5.50 -0.019500
Mean     5.50 -0.005856
3rd Qu.  7.75  0.695200
Max.    10.00  0.987600
```